# Active record query in rails with conditional join

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

- I have models `Category` and `Deal` and having `has_many :through` mapping via `categories_deals`.
- I have a another model, `City`, which has a `has_many :through` mapping via `cities_deals`   with `deals`.

Now I want to fetch deals in category 2 and 3 and city 10.

```
CategoriesDeal.where(:category_id=>[2,3])
```

Like how to specify city now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution.. Here it is:

```
Deal.all(:joins=>[:cities, :categories], :conditions=>["cities.id= ? and categories.id IN (?)",2, [62,43]]).uniq
```